# Laravel's naming convention

Tags: laravel

If the Model is `Company` it's table name is `companies` if we do not override `protected $table` property. And if it is `Book`, table name is `books`. So why not `companys` How does laravel understand English and grammer? Where are these words listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Illuminate/Pluralizer](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.html) is responsible to get the inflection of an English word. It defines a set of uncountable words like:

```
public static $uncountable = [
    'audio',
    'bison',
    ...

    'species',
    'swine',
    'traffic',
    'wheat',
];
```

The `Pluralizer` internally uses [`doctrine/inflector`](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php) which defines the actual logic (collected from several different php projects by several different authors) to inflect a word. `Inflector` has general rules to *plularize* and *singularize* words, and also defines words which are uninflected, or have irregular plurals.

```
private static $plural = array(
    'rules' => array(
        ...
        '/(x|ch|ss|sh)$/i' => '\1es',
        '/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/i' => '\1\2ves',
        '/us$/i' => 'uses',
        ...
    ),
    'uninflected' => array(
        '.*[nrlm]ese', '.*deer', '.*fish', ..., 'people', 'cookie'
    ),
    'irregular' => array(
        'atlas' => 'atlases',
        'axe' => 'axes',
        'beef' => 'beefs',
        ...
        'trilby' => 'trilbys',
        'turf' => 'turfs',
        'volcano' => 'volcanoes',
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel is smart enough to use real words. For example, it will use `media` table for `Media` model.

If you'll see in the source code, you'll see how does Laravel builds table name:

```
return str_replace('\\', '', Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this))));
```

First, Laravel uses `Pluralizer::plural()` to create plural and then converts it to snake case.

Comment: if you create a model Media i think laravel will by default "think" the table for Media model is medias....is this true or false??

Comment: No, Laravel will try to use `media` table by default.